# JavaScript form validation, string length

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a formValidation for JavaScript, everything is working but I'm facing a problem now with the length. It actually works and give me the alert, but never pass it when I put 8 or more characters in the password field.

**I'm sure there is a small mistake that I need to be aware of, please advice!**

```
if(!document.getElementById("username").value)
{
    alert("Username field is required!");
    return false;

}

if(!document.getElementById("password").value)
{
    alert("Password field is required!");
    return false;

}

if(!document.getElementById("password").length < 8);
{
    alert("Password should contain at least 8 characters!");
    return false;       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition contains a semicolon at the end which makes it an expression rather than a condition

```
if(!document.getElementById("password").length < 8);  <-- ERROR
```

Change your last condition to this:

```
if(document.getElementById("password").value.length < 8) {
    alert("Password should contain at least 8 characters!");
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: See another edit.. @MustafaA. .. the culprit is the semicolon at the end of your `if` condition

Comment: Am glad that I have helped